# Proof of the relationship between fibonacci numbers and pascal's triangle, without induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

http://s0.goldennumber.net/wp-content/uploads/pascals-triangle-fibonacci.gif

I must prove, without induction, the relationship above is:

$$\sum _{ k=0 }^{ \lfloor n/2\rfloor}{ \binom{n-k}k } ={F}_{n+1}$$

I understand how the equation works but I have no idea how to prove it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Note, you can't even define this sort of question without induction. So you can't really prove it "without induction," you can just hide the induction in some supplemental theorem/lemma.

Comment: Weird, my prof said to prove without induction. Perhaps he meant to just explain how we get to this equation? I'm not sure how the equation is derived...

Comment: It depends on what other theorems you are allowed to use - as I say, it is possible to "hide" induction by appealing to other theorems.

Comment: Perhaps the exercise isn't to *prove* anything, but merely to convert the illustrated relation into a formal equation (as a prelude to later proof) ... but that's not much of an exercise.

Comment: For example, if you know a closed form for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty F_k z^k$, you can prove this theorem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty F_k z^k = \frac{z}{1-z-z^2}$$

Then you can prove this by using that $\frac{1}{1-w} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty w^k$ where $w=z+z^2$.

Comment: We haven't discussed this in class so I'm assuming we just have to explain the equation. For example, why do we use the floor function?

Comment: @Justin If you dislike the floor function, consider when $n$ is even and odd.

Comment: The reason is just that if $k> n/2$, $n-k<k$, so $\binom{n-k}k = 0$. Therefore you could just write: $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n-k}k$$ Obviously, if $k\leq n/2$ then $k\leq\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ - the end term of $\sum$ needs to be an integer.

Comment: So the floor function is only used to avoid making unnecessary calculations (i.e. adding zero to the sum)?

Comment: And to make the end an integer. If you just wrote $\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}$, that wouldn't make sense if $n$ was odd.

Comment: Okay makes sense. I need a little clarification on the combination term, how does it describe the diagonal of the triangle? When n is 1 does that describe the apex of the triangle only?

Comment: When $n=0$ it is the apex. When $n=1$, it is just the single element $\binom{1}{0}$. For $n=2$ it is $\binom{2}{0} + \binom{1}{1}$...

Comment: Okay, thanks a bunch for your help!